# Convert string to date and add 5 days to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like so

```
"2014-10-29"
```

and Now I need to convert it to a date and add 5 days to it.

I have this code that adds 5 days to the current date, but how would I convert that string to a date and add 5 days to it?

```
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 5);

var yyyy = newDate.getFullYear().toString();
var mm = (newDate.getMonth() + 1).toString();
var dd = newDate.getDate().toString();

var mmChars = mm.split('');
var ddChars = dd.split('');

var newClosingDate = yyyy + '-' + (mmChars[1] ? mm : "0" + mmChars[0]) + '-' + (ddChars[1] ? dd : "0" + ddChars[0]);
```

Comment: If you are going to manipulate a lot of dates you could use the [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: @Aaron, same idea as me - I need to learn to type faster :D

Comment: Can you add the five days before turning it to a string? Or is adding the days after a requirement? I ask because you can pass raw date strings to `date()` and get a date as the output. You could have that add 5 days to just like you have it but place your date string in the date function `date('2014-10-29') +5`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the string in to the `Date` constructor:

```js
var newDate = new Date("2014-10-29");
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 5);

var yyyy = newDate.getFullYear().toString();
var mm = (newDate.getMonth() + 1).toString();
var dd = newDate.getDate().toString();

var mmChars = mm.split('');
var ddChars = dd.split('');

var newClosingDate = yyyy + '-' + (mmChars[1] ? mm : "0" + mmChars[0]) + '-' + (ddChars[1] ? dd : "0" + ddChars[0]);

console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the wonderful library called [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - it makes working with dates in JavaScript an absolute breeze. Especially converting them back and forth to/from strings.

With your date and using moment, you could do this for example:

```
var stringFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD', 
    date = moment('2014-10-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD');

date.add(5, 'days');

console.log(date.format(stringFormat);
```

This will print out the string in the same format as you put in.